# Как в canvas изменить ширину блоков относительно размеров из массива?

Tags: javascript, canvas

`let data = [2, 35, 11, 93, 42, 4, 74];`

`2` ширина блока 0px - `drawBar(ctx, x, y, 0, h, '#000');` - минимальный размер

`93` ширина блока `canvasWidth / data.length` ~ 28px - `drawBar(ctx, x, y, 28, h, '#000');` - максимальный размер

Нужно правильный `w` подставлять в `drawBar(ctx, x, y, w, h, '#000');`

```js
function drawLine(ctx, startX, startY, endX, endY, color){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawBar(ctx, x, y, w, h, color){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    ctx.restore();
}

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth +'px';
canvas.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight +'px';
let canvasWidth = canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * 2;
let canvasHeight = canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * 2;

let data = [2, 35, 11, 93, 42, 4, 74];

let w = canvasWidth / data.length;
let h = canvasHeight / data.length;
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  drawLine(ctx, x, 0, x, canvasHeight, '#cfcfcf')
  drawBar(ctx, x, y, w, h, '#000'); // w - ширина этого блока
  x += w;
  y += h;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Пытаюсь еще так делать, но пока все без результатно

```js
let max = 93;
let min = 2;
let width = 200;
let data = [2, 35, 11, 93, 42, 4, 74];
let col = width / data.length;
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  console.log( data[i], col % data[i] );
}
```

```
2 0
35 ?
11 ?
93 28.571428571428573
42 ?
4 ?
74 ?
```

Пытаюсь сделать что то типа такого [prnt.sc/11n2orp](http://prnt.sc/11n2orp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[2, 35, 11, 93, 42, 4, 74]` взять из массива максимальное число: `93`.

Есть некая ширина `unitWidth = canvasWidth / колво_элементов_массива`, отведенная для каждой "ячейки" массива (максимальное «93» должно заполнять её полностью).

`unitWidth / 93` будет показывать, сколько ширины должна занимать «единица» из массива. Соответственно, каждое число будет занимать такую ширину: `число * (unitWidth / 93)`

```js
function drawLine(ctx, startX, startY, endX, endY, color) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawBar(ctx, x, y, w, h, color) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.restore();
}

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth + 'px';
canvas.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight + 'px';
let canvasWidth = canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * 2;
let canvasHeight = canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * 2;

let data = [2, 35, 11, 93, 42, 4, 74];

// выше - не трогал.
let max = Math.max(...data); // 93
let unitWid = canvasWidth / data.length;
let boxHei = canvasHeight / data.length;

let x = 0, y = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let boxWid = unitWid * (data[i] / max);
  
  drawLine(ctx, x, 0, x, canvasHeight, '#cfcfcf');
  drawBar(ctx, x, y, boxWid, boxHei, '#000');
  
  x += unitWid;
  y += boxHei;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Только ширина самих колонок должна быть фиксированной, одна колонка равна `canvasWidth / data.length`, а сами блоки просто не на всю ширину выделенной ей колонки заполняются

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать что то типа такого https://prnt.sc/11n2orp

Comment: @Squeli47 Ага, отредактировано. Такие картинки было бы полезно сразу добавлять в вопрос)

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Добавил картинку в вопрос